# Mlflow UI can't show artifacts

Tags: docker, docker-compose, azure-blob-storage, mlflow

I have mlflow running on an azure VM and connected to Azure Blob as the artifact storage.

After uploading artifacts to the storage from the Client.

I tried the MLflow UI and successfully was able to show the uploaded file.

The problem happens when I try to run MLFLOW with Docker, I get the error:
**Unable to list artifacts stored under `{artifactUri}` for the current run. Please contact your tracking server administrator to notify them of this error, which can happen when the tracking server lacks permission to list artifacts under the current run's root artifact directory**

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim-buster
# Install python packages
RUN pip install mlflow pymysql

RUN pip install azure-storage-blob

ENV AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY="#########"
ENV AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING="#######"
```

docker-compose.yml

```
web:
        restart: always
        build: ./mlflow_server
        image: mlflow_server
        container_name: mlflow_server
        expose:
            - "5000"
        networks:
            - frontend
            - backend
        environment:
            - AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY="#####"
            - AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING="#####"
        command: mlflow server --backend-store-uri mysql+pymysql://mlflow_user:123456@db:3306/mlflow --default-artifact-root wasbs://etc..
```

I tried multiple solutions:

1. Making sure that boto3 is installed (Didn't do anything)
2. Adding Environment Variables in the Dockerfile so the command runs after they're set
3. I double checked the url of the storage blob

And MLFLOW doesn't show any logs it just kills the process and restarts again.

Anyone got any idea what might be the solution or how can i access the logs

here're the docker logs of the container:

```
[2022-07-28 12:23:33 +0000] [10] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.1.0
[2022-07-28 12:23:33 +0000] [10] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (10)
[2022-07-28 12:23:33 +0000] [10] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2022-07-28 12:23:33 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
[2022-07-28 12:23:33 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14
[2022-07-28 12:23:33 +0000] [15] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15
[2022-07-28 12:23:33 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16
[2022-07-28 12:24:24 +0000] [10] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14)
[2022-07-28 12:24:24 +0000] [14] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14)
[2022-07-28 12:24:24 +0000] [21] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21
```